# The header portion is not visible while the keyboard moves upward

Tags: android, layout

I got a problem regarding layout,when i type in the textbox the querty keyboard gets upward but at the same time the screen also moves up,

here is the xml

http://pastie.org/private/3ooipci4ipo36aaqdlasxw

i have added android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateHidden"  but it does not make any change.could somebody help me out,here i have attach the layout

first with having some messages..

[image]

second one when the keyboard moves up..the first message is missing!

[image]

could anybody help me out thanks!

Comment: Do you have added weight to your textviews that contain the chat?

Comment: I think you have to add weight="1" to your TextViews containing the chat

Comment: let me try @basnijkamp

Comment: Does the relativelayout chat_content contains the chat? if yes, place your modified xml here. So I can see what you have edited

Comment: @basnijkamp yes..i have added the chat content which is in relative layout

Comment: @priya show your manifest file code

Comment: that is listview know then how can maintain old messages at top

Comment: the messages which you are shows by using listview know?

Comment: Then how you are expecting the old messages to always show when keyboard appears?

Comment: @Santosh what should i do now to get the messages

Comment: You to scroll the listview after keyboard appears....